# How to cancel a rn-fetch-blob task when App enters from background to foreground

Tags: react-native

Here is my code

```
componentDidMount(): void {
        this.download();
}

download =()=>{
        this.downloader = RNFetchBlob.config({
            fileCache: true,
            path: `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/${fileName}`,
        }).fetch('GET', url, {
            //some headers ..
        }).progress((received, total) => {
        console.log('Progress', received / total);
        }).then(async (res) => {

            console.log(res.path())

        }).catch(async (errorMessage, statusCode) => {
            console.log(errorMessage);
            console.log(statusCode);
        })
}
```

I'm using above code to download a list of large files (around 1GB to 2GB) and everything work just fine when app state is in foreground/active but sometimes when i turn display off or just using another app while it's downloading and somehow the OS (android) might killed my app or put it into sleep mode and when i open the app again i can see the app is start from scratch and the variable `this.downloader` is set to null BUT i still can see logs write out in .process() method, it means the OS killed my app but somehow the process of rn-fetch-blob is still downloading and it will execute `this.download();` method again and create a new rn-fetch-blob download task so there will be a duplicate download task for the same file. Cuz the app is start from scratch when it was downloading and killed or suspended by the OS so the `this.downloader` of previous download task is null and i don't know how to cancel the previous task before create a new one.

Comment: Which version of React Native are you using? You might be able to use AbortController - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController - added in 0.60

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've a look into it, as far as i know AbortController can be used to cancel a Fetch request but we need to define it and assign it to a variable which will be reset to null in this issue. To clarify, all variables that created before the app going to sleep or terminated by OS will be set to null when the app comes to active again.